# AngularJS how to process excel file without getting errors because of column names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that process an excel file, and puts the contents of the file into an array, to later be  displayed on an html table.

The excel file has to have always the correct header names otherwise it does not work.

Is there a way to modify the function so that the header names are not relevant for the file to be processed?

There will always be 4 columns and the data will always be in the appropiate column, the header names should not matter

This is my angularJS code:

```
$scope.DisplayFile = function () {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
    if (regex.test($scope.SelectedFile.name.toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) !== "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            //For Browsers other than IE.
            if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $scope.ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString($scope.SelectedFile);
            } else {
                //For IE Browser.
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var data = "";
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                        data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                    }
                    $scope.ProcessExcel(data);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.SelectedFile);
            }
        } else {
            $window.alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    } else {
        $window.alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
    }
};

$scope.ProcessExcel = function (data) {
    //Read the Excel File data.
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
    });
    //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
    var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
    excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
    //Display the data from Excel file in Table.
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.AgendaItems = excelRows;
     });
};
```

and the html

```
<table class="table mt-4 mb-5" id="tblCrossReference" ng-show="IsVisible">
    <tr>
        <th>Meeting ID</th>
        <th>Agenda Item</th>
        <th>Legistar ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="ai in AgendaItems">   
        <tr>
            <td>{{ai.MeetingID}}</td>
            <td>{{ai.AgendaItem}}</td>
            <td>{{ai.LegistarID}}</td>
            <td>{{ai.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to provide your own header names so you will not be dependent on header names in excel.

> XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:["A","E","I","O","U","6","9"]});

The above function takes a header parameter. Using this you can provide own headers.
One slight problem with this is, it will consider your headers in excel also as data row.
This can be sorted by removing first item from **excelRows** array in your code.

So, you can now write angularJS code as :

```
       excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet], { header: ["Myheader1", "Myheader2", "Myheader3", "Myheader4"] });
            //Display the data from Excel file in Table.
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                excelRows.shift();
                $scope.AgendaItems = excelRows;
            });
```

and in HTML :

```
             <table class="table mt-4 mb-5" id="tblCrossReference" ng-show="IsVisible">
                <tr>
                    <th>Meeting ID</th>
                    <th>Agenda Item</th>
                    <th>Legistar ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody ng-repeat="ai in AgendaItems">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ai.Myheader1}}</td>
                        <td>{{ai.Myheader2}}</td>
                        <td>{{ai.Myheader3}}</td>
                        <td>{{ai.Myheader4}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

SheetJS documentation here :https://docs.sheetjs.com/

Comment: Hello @gkulshrestha - Your solution looks promising. I say that just because I hope I implement it correctly. Let me try that and report back. Thank you!